# Timer not stopping when wanted to and stopping when not wanted to Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, timer, segue

The storyboard is set up onto 2 VC's. The `initial VC` just has a button which `segues` to where the `battleScene` takes place. The `battleScene` has a button which `segues` back to the `initial VC`, a label to show the health, and a button to start the timer.

I have 2 issues that i've been trying to work out and haven't figured out.

1: when I play the `NSTimer` then switch VC's and go back to the VC in which the timer is effecting the label the label stops updating.

2: When enemy2's health is 0 and I tell the timer to stop using my `stopTimer` method the timers continues.

```
int enemy001Hp = 100;
int enemy002Hp = 200;

bool enemy001Active = NO;
bool enemy002Active = NO;

- (void) enemy1 {
enemy001Active = YES;
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy001Hp];
}
- (void) enemy2 {
enemy002Active = YES;
self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy002Hp];
}

- (void) enemyDamageTimer {
if (enemy001Active == YES) {
    enemy001Hp -= 50;
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",enemy001Hp];
    if (enemy001Hp <= 0) {
        [self enemy2];
        self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy002Hp];
        enemy001Active = NO;
        enemy002Active = YES;
    }
} else if (enemy002Active == YES) {
    enemy002Hp -=50;
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy002Hp];
}
}

- (void) stopTimer {
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self enemy1];
if (enemy002Active == YES) {
    self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", enemy002Hp];
}  
}

- (IBAction)idleAttack:(id)sender {
self.idleOutler.hidden = YES;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(enemyDamageTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if (enemy001Active == YES) {
    if (enemy001Hp <= 0) {
        [self enemy2];
        enemy001Active = NO;
        enemy002Active = YES;
    }
} else if (enemy002Active == YES) {
    if (enemy002Hp <= 0) {
        self.enemyHpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
        enemy002Hp = 0;
        enemy002Active = NO;
        [self stopTimer];
    }
}
}
```

I got the `stopTimer` method from a timer guide and I've been looking around to find how to resolve the timer stopping on segue issue to no resolve.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For the question 1 there is nothing wrong in your code about timer, so the problem probably remains in VC transition code

For question 2 the timer will repeatedly fire method `enemyDamageTimer` in which you never called `stopTimer`. That's why the timer continues

Comment: So as long as I put the `stopTimer` method inside the `enemyDamageTimer` it will actually stop? Also, for Q1 I have no code for the VC transition what can I do to make it work?